# Induction proof of sentence

Tags: induction

How do I prove that

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{2i - 1}{2i}) \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n + 1}}
$

using induction for n > 0 ?

In general, for (n+1) case, I split the productory in:

```
factor(n+1) *  productory [i, n] factor(i)
```

given productory [i, n] factor(i) is the hypothesis, we replace for

```
factor(n+1) * [right_side_of_hypotesis - K]
    where K is the difference between the sides of the hypothesis
```

I couldn't get out of this stage...

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We do not make a habit of answering questions in which no effort is shown by the asker. Try including what you have tried so far so others are more willing to help you. Also, read this guide on how to ask a good question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I've done lot of work on it but I'm not used to LaTeX so I didn't write everything I did till I run out of ideas

Answer (score 3):

I am going to show $\qquad\frac{2n-1}{2n}\le\frac{\sqrt{3n-2}}{\sqrt{3n+1}},\quad$ which can be re-written as $$1-\frac{1}{2n}\le\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{3n+1}}\tag{1}$$

By squaring, we have ($1$) is equivalent to
\begin{align}
&&1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}&\le 1-\frac{3}{3n+1}\\
\iff&&\frac{3}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{4n^2}&\le \frac{1}{n}\\
\iff&&4n^2(3)+3n+1&\le4n(3n+1)\\
\iff&&12n^2+3n+1&\le12n^2 +4n\\
\iff&&1&\le n
\end{align}
Last inequality holds, then we have 
$$\frac{2n-1}{2n}\le\frac{\sqrt{3n-2}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\;\;\implies \;\;\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{2i-1}{2i}\le\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{3i-2}}{\sqrt{3i+1}}\;\;\iff\;\;\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{2i-1}{2i}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$$

---

**What about using induction?**

1) You must show that the inequality holds for $n=1$, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}$.

2)Inductive hypothesis: let's suppose the inequality $$\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{2i-1}{2i}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}$$ holds for $k\ge 1$.

3) *Show*, from steps 1) and 2) that
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{2i-1}{2i}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(k+1)+1}}\;\; \text{holds}$$
It can be done as I did above for showing that ($1$) holds.

Comment: Actually, that *is* induction. You just first proved the theorem needed to make the induction step work.